# Migrating from SO to here

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I started a [meta Q](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144078/when-to-start-and-migrate-salesforce-related-questions-to-the-new-site) on SO, regarding migrating questions to here.

I think that we need to support this transition.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144078/when-to-start-and-migrate-salesforce-related-questions-to-the-new-site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion is to focus on writing great questions and answers for this site. This site is just out of private beta and hasn't yet had the opportunity to solve any of the problems that are common for many new beta sites.

Right now, the best course of action is to focus on the 7 essential questions of a beta site. Figure out what the elevator pitch is, focus on what questions are on topic and what questions are off topic based on what you see happening on the site. What about tags? How will questions be organized? Based on actions so far on the site and in meta, who are likely candidates for pro-temp moderators? Once you solve these challenges, how will you promote the site so it isn't just a dumping ground dependent on Stack Overflow for content?

In my experience, it's best not to grow too fast. People asking on Stack Overflow already have an idea of what the expectations are in that community, and forcing migrations here without having the above questions answered could create quality problems for this site.

In summary, focus on the internal details first. After a few months, assuming things have stabilized, you could then ask your appointed pro-temp moderators to discuss possible migrations with other moderators.  However, unless the questions are really amazing questions that meet all Stack Exchange guidelines, and unless the questions are actually off-topic on Stack Overflow, the likelihood of them being migrated is fairly small. For the most part, we only migrate questions away from a community if that question doesn't fit within that community and is off-topic there. Hope this helps!